# Transpose 1st and 3rd row from CSV file into columns in shell sripts

Tags: linux, shell, unix, hadoop

I need to transpose the 1st and 3rd row from CSV file and need to append some keywords in that.
for E.g. I have a file which contains data like this.

```
Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Test1_AA_Col8,Test1_AA_Col9,Test1_AA_Col10,Test1_BB_col11,Test1_BB_col12,Test1_BB_col13,Test2_AA_col14,Test2_AA_col15,Test2_AA_cl16,Test2_BB_col17,Test2_BB_col18,Test2_BB_col19,Test3_AA_col20,Test3_AA_col21,Test3_AA_col22,Test3_BB_col23,Test3_BB_col24,Test3_BB_col25,Test4_AA_col26,Test4_AA_cl27,Test4_AA_col28,Test4_BB_col29,Test4_BB_col30,Test4_BB_col31
```

object,object,object,object,object,object,object,float64,float64,float64,float64,float64,float64,float64,float64,float64,float64,float64,float64,float64,float64,float64,float64,float64,float64,float64,float64,float64,float64,float64,float64
String,String,String,String,String,String,String,"Decimal(35,15)","Decimal(35,15)","Decimal(35,15)","Decimal(35,15)","Decimal(35,15)","Decimal(35,15)","Decimal(35,15)","Decimal(35,15)","Decimal(35,15)","Decimal(35,15)","Decimal(35,15)","Decimal(35,15)","Decimal(35,15)","Decimal(35,15)","Decimal(35,15)","Decimal(35,15)","Decimal(35,15)","Decimal(35,15)","Decimal(35,15)","Decimal(35,15)","Decimal(35,15)","Decimal(35,15)","Decimal(35,15)","Decimal(35,15)"

I tried to transpose 1st and 3rd row and my output look like this

```
CAST(Col1 AS String) AS Col1,
CAST(Col2 AS String) AS Col2,
CAST(Col3 AS String) AS Col3,
CAST(Col4 AS String) AS Col4,
CAST(Col5 AS String) AS Col5,
CAST(Col6 AS String) AS Col6,
CAST(Col7 AS String) AS Col7,
CAST(Test1_AA_Col8 AS Decimal(35,15)) AS Test1_AA_Col8,
CAST(Test1_AA_Col9 AS Decimal(35,15)) AS Test1_AA_Col9,
CAST(Test1_AA_Col10 AS Decimal(35,15)) AS Test1_AA_Col10,
CAST(Test1_BB_col11 AS Decimal(35,15)) AS Test1_BB_col11,
CAST(Test1_BB_col12 AS Decimal(35,15)) AS Test1_BB_col12,
CAST(Test1_BB_col13 AS Decimal(35,15)) AS Test1_BB_col13,
CAST(Test2_AA_col14 AS Decimal(35,15)) AS Test2_AA_col14,
CAST(Test2_AA_col15 AS Decimal(35,15)) AS Test2_AA_col15,
CAST(Test2_AA_cl16 AS Decimal(35,15)) AS Test2_AA_cl16,
CAST(Test2_BB_col17 AS Decimal(35,15)) AS Test2_BB_col17,
CAST(Test2_BB_col18 AS Decimal(35,15)) AS Test2_BB_col18,
CAST(Test2_BB_col19 AS Decimal(35,15)) AS Test2_BB_col19,
CAST(Test3_AA_col20 AS Decimal(35,15)) AS Test3_AA_col20,
CAST(Test3_AA_col21 AS Decimal(35,15)) AS Test3_AA_col21,
CAST(Test3_AA_col22 AS Decimal(35,15)) AS Test3_AA_col22,
CAST(Test3_BB_col23 AS Decimal(35,15)) AS Test3_BB_col23,
CAST(Test3_BB_col24 AS Decimal(35,15)) AS Test3_BB_col24,
CAST(Test3_BB_col25 AS Decimal(35,15)) AS Test3_BB_col25,
CAST(Test4_AA_col26 AS Decimal(35,15)) AS Test4_AA_col26,
CAST(Test4_AA_cl27 AS Decimal(35,15)) AS Test4_AA_cl27,
CAST(Test4_AA_col28 AS Decimal(35,15)) AS Test4_AA_col28,
CAST(Test4_BB_col29 AS Decimal(35,15)) AS Test4_BB_col29,
CAST(Test4_BB_col30 AS Decimal(35,15)) AS Test4_BB_col30,
) AS Test4_BB_col31
```

This is the code I have written.

```
hadoop fs -text $f | sed -n '1p;3p' | awk -F, '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) a[i,NR=$i; max=(max<NF?NF:max)} END {for (i=1; i<=max; i++) {for (j=1; j<=NR;j++) printf "%s%s" , a[i,j], (i==NR?RS:FS) }}'
```

This is what I want to achieve.

```
CAST(Col1 AS String) AS Col1,
CAST(Col2 AS String) AS Col2,
CAST(Col3 AS String) AS Col3,
CAST(Col4 AS String) AS Col4,
CAST(Col5 AS String) AS Col5,
CAST(Col6 AS String) AS Col6,
CAST(Col7 AS String) AS Col7,
CAST(Test1_AA_Col8 AS Decimal(35,15)) AS Test1_AA_Col8,
CAST(Test1_AA_Col9 AS Decimal(35,15)) AS Test1_AA_Col9,
CAST(Test1_AA_Col10 AS Decimal(35,15)) AS Test1_AA_Col10,
CAST(Test1_BB_col11 AS Decimal(35,15)) AS Test1_BB_col11,
CAST(Test1_BB_col12 AS Decimal(35,15)) AS Test1_BB_col12,
CAST(Test1_BB_col13 AS Decimal(35,15)) AS Test1_BB_col13,
CAST(Test2_AA_col14 AS Decimal(35,15)) AS Test2_AA_col14,
CAST(Test2_AA_col15 AS Decimal(35,15)) AS Test2_AA_col15,
CAST(Test2_AA_cl16 AS Decimal(35,15)) AS Test2_AA_cl16,
CAST(Test2_BB_col17 AS Decimal(35,15)) AS Test2_BB_col17,
CAST(Test2_BB_col18 AS Decimal(35,15)) AS Test2_BB_col18,
CAST(Test2_BB_col19 AS Decimal(35,15)) AS Test2_BB_col19,
CAST(Test3_AA_col20 AS Decimal(35,15)) AS Test3_AA_col20,
CAST(Test3_AA_col21 AS Decimal(35,15)) AS Test3_AA_col21,
CAST(Test3_AA_col22 AS Decimal(35,15)) AS Test3_AA_col22,
CAST(Test3_BB_col23 AS Decimal(35,15)) AS Test3_BB_col23,
CAST(Test3_BB_col24 AS Decimal(35,15)) AS Test3_BB_col24,
CAST(Test3_BB_col25 AS Decimal(35,15)) AS Test3_BB_col25,
CAST(Test4_AA_col26 AS Decimal(35,15)) AS Test4_AA_col26,
CAST(Test4_AA_cl27 AS Decimal(35,15)) AS Test4_AA_cl27,
CAST(Test4_AA_col28 AS Decimal(35,15)) AS Test4_AA_col28,
CAST(Test4_BB_col29 AS Decimal(35,15)) AS Test4_BB_col29,
CAST(Test4_BB_col30 AS Decimal(35,15)) AS Test4_BB_col30,
CAST(Test4_BB_col31 AS Decimal(35,15)) AS Test4_BB_col31
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From given sample to expected output using GNU awk (if using `FPAT`, not `FS`):

```
$ awk '
BEGIN {
    # FS=","                        # no quoted fields
    FPAT="([^,]*)|(\"[^\"]+\")"
}
NR==1 {
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
        a[i]=$i
}
NR==3 {
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        gsub(/^"|"$/,"",$i)
        printf "CAST(%s AS %s) AS %s%s\n",a[i],$i,a[i],(i==NF?"":",")
    }
    exit
}' file
```

Output:

```
CAST(Col1 AS String) AS Col1,
CAST(Col2 AS String) AS Col2,
CAST(Col3 AS Bigint) AS Col3,
CAST(Col4 AS Int) AS Col4,
CAST(Col5 AS String) AS Col5
```

One-liner for your plumbing:

```
$ ... | awk 'BEGIN{FPAT="([^,]*)|(\"[^\"]+\")"}NR==1{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)a[i]=$i}NR==3{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){gsub(/^"|"$/,"",$i);printf "CAST(%s AS %s) AS %s%s\n",a[i],$i,a[i],(i==NF?"":",")}exit}'
```

**Updated** output with quoted fields:

```
CAST(Col1 AS String) AS Col1,
CAST(Col2 AS String) AS Col2,
CAST(Col3 AS Bigint) AS Col3,
CAST(Col4 AS Int) AS Col4,
CAST(Col5 AS String) AS Col5,
CAST(Col6 AS Decimal (35,2)) AS Col6
```

**Update** A version for `FPAT`less awks. It has an entry-level parser to deal with commas in (single pair of) double quotes (`\"` not handled correctly):

```
awk '
function parse(str,    i,j,n,q) {
    for(i=1;i<=length(str);i++) {
        if(i==length(str)||(substr(str,i+1,1)=="," && q==0)) {
            b[++n]=substr(str,j+1,i-j)
            j=i+1
        }
        if(substr(str,i+1,1)=="\"")
            q=(!q)
    }
    return n
}
BEGIN {
    FS=","
}
NR==1 {
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
        a[i]=$i
}
NR==3 {
    n=parse($0)
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++) {
        gsub(/^"|"$/,"",b[i])
        printf "CAST(%s AS %s) AS %s%s\n",a[i],b[i],a[i],(i==n?"":",")
    }
    exit
}' file
```

Comment: Thanks James for your reply. But it's not working correctly when my data contains columns as below Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6
AA,AA,AA,AA,AA,AA
String,String,Bigint,Int,String,"Decimal (35,2)"

Comment: Please, update changed requirements to the OP along with the expected output.

Comment: Updated, better? Trailing space after `"` might cause problems.

Comment: I don't know why but I am getting output like this.
CAST(Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,col7,Col8,Col9 AS String,String,Bigint,String,String,String,String,String,"Decimal) AS Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,col7,Col8,Col9,
CAST( AS (35,2)) AS

Comment: `FPAT` is GNU awk only. Which awk are you using?

Comment: gcc version 4.4.7 (Red Hat 4.4.7-16) is that what you want?

Comment: No, awk version. Probably `awk --version` or `awk -W version`.

Comment: This is the version. GNU Awk 3.1.7

Comment: OK, `FPAT` was introduced in version 4. Let me whip up something.

Comment: It is showing me the correct result for the above file. But when I try it on my actual file which has some more columns in it, it is showing me correct result except the last column. 
CAST(A500 AS Timestamp) AS A500,
) AS A600al(35,15)" 
where Timestamp is my second last column data type and Decimal(35,15) is my last column data type(A500 and A600 are column name )

Comment: Any idea James why this is happening (See my above comment)?

Comment: Sorry, missed that earlier comment. Can't really fix on such a description only. Try to make a (minimal) failing data set, post it and I'll have a look.

Comment: James, Updated the code with required output.. Hope this help to find solution

Comment: Your file has WIndows line endings, ie. `\r\n` instead of `\n` as used in Unix/Linux and probably by default used by your awk. You can fix that with, for example, adding `RS="\r\n"` to the `BEGIN` block. I usually use `RS="\r?\n"` like all the time. (Tested with GNU awk 3.1.8, 4.14, mawk 1.3.3, Busybox awk and  awk version 20121220)